# Split up messy column to several rows in excel file

Tags: python, r

I have a csv file in which 2 of the cols has a lot of info that I want split up (see example below), and I want to split the column and make into rows, however I do not have a specific delimiter I can just use while reading in the file into pandas as the data is very messy. P.S, i used random letters/ numbers instead of the actual info in there, but it goes something like name, id, age, time, etc... (note not all the info is stored in strings in the actual data, some are just integers)
I know about .split(), but I don't think that would work with what I want. any help is appreciated.

```
   v1                                            |v2 
   ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
x |1                                             | 2 
y |"n": "k", "f": "a", "m", C", "z": "2","4","1" |"n": "j", "f": "l", "n", q", "z": "5","9", "13"
v |8                                             |9
```

how would i make it like this:

```
   v1            | v2
-------------------------
x |1             |2
n |"k"           |"j"
f |"a", "m", "c" | "l", "n", "q"
z |"2","4","1"   | "5","9", "13"
v |8             | 9
```

Comment: Why is this tagged R when you're asking about Pandas?

Comment: Can you provide the raw csv file ? Or at least the relevant part.

Comment: I tagged R because if there was a relevant solution in R, I'd do it in R instead of python/pandas

Comment: I cannot provide the raw csv file because it is confidential, but this gives a pretty good idea of what it looks like

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Using R and assuming

- the data shown reproducibly in the Note at the end and
- we want to split the complex strings at the colons

separate the rows using `separate_rows` and then trim the whitespace off the ends of both columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

d %>%
  separate_rows(v1, v2, sep = ":") %>%
  mutate(v1 = trimws(v1), v2 = trimws(v2))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  v1                         v2                        
  <chr>                      <chr>                     
1 "1"                        "2"                       
2 "\"n\""                    "\"n\""                   
3 "\"k\", \"f\""             "\"j\", \"f\""            
4 "\"a\", \"m\", C\", \"z\"" "\"l\", \"n\", q\", \"z\""
5 "\"2\",\"4\",\"1\""        "\"5\",\"9\", \"13\""     
6 "8"                        "9"
```

### Note

```
Lines <- 'v1                                           |v2 
x |1                                             | 2 
y |"n": "k", "f": "a", "m", C", "z": "2","4","1" |"n": "j", "f": "l", "n", q", "z": "5","9", "13"
v |8                                             |9'
d <- read.table(text = Lines, sep = "|", strip.white = TRUE, quote = "")
```